# How to change the availability of territories of a released iOS app in Apple app store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, region, iphone-developer-program

We are trying to change the availability of  territories of a released `iOS` app in `Apple` app store
Unfortunately, a bug of iTunes connect prevent us from changing availability.
And we got a **JS error** on the page
[image]

Comment: Can you also please state, whether the app is live & wanting to change territories. But in both case [App is live & app is to be submitted] as per my knowledge you can change the number of territories & also can have 0 terrorise also. Can you please retry & post comment likewise.

Comment: Also do you have (The given user) in the team have privilege to change this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be helpful:
As per apple documentation:

> Only users with the Admin, Technical, or App Manager role can access
>   the Pricing and Availability section to make changes. Users with the
>   Marketer role can access this section but cannot make changes.

[image]

Comment: My case is there is a JS error when I click the "Edit" link on the page, and when I tried to Edit again yesterday, the JS error did not appear, and I am able to change the Availability successfully. This answer might be helpful for other guys. Thanks anyway.