# How long does changes take when you remove an app from sale in App Store using App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, app-store-connect

My app is accepted by Apple Store Connect. However I need to fix some mistakes and submit again. Meanwhile I like to remove it from live store. I followed the directions found here [how-to-change-the-availability-of-territories-of-a-released-ios-app-in-apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366695/how-to-change-the-availability-of-territories-of-a-released-ios-app-in-apple-app?rq=1). How long does it take that my app to be removed from the app store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Usually in 1 hour but max is within 24 hours it will no longer available in app store.**

[image]

reference link - https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev7013b314c

Comment: I have talked with Apple support, and the expected time is "a couple of hours". And yes it was 1 and half hour.